# Effects of Game-based Learning on Motivation for Learning

Tags: learning, motivation, educational-psychology, gamification, incentives

I have already asked this question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/69216/effects-of-game-based-learning-on-motivation-for-learning), but I did not receive my answer. I found this site a more appropriate place to ask it.

I found many studies discovering the impacts of game-based learning on motivation for learning.

[For example, these papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=game-based%20learning%20impact%20motivation)

You can also find a summary of them in [this book chapter](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-3185-5_38).

However, it is still unclear to me if this motivation is for entertainment or for learning. I was wondering if there is any study showing that students who are adapted to this method of learning have a higher motivation to pursue learning in other forms. My concern is about long-term effects of this method of learning. What is the intrinsic reaction of K-12 students who have adapted to game-based learning when they start higher education in which game-based learning is not provided? Will they have a higher incentive to study? or a lower incentive, because they prefer to play games rather than studying?

Comment: Try a simple experiment or compare the performance (students who engage in game and do not engage). do pre-assessment then post-assessment to determine the before and after performance.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends.

If the game is good, the player will be motivated to learn what they need to succeed in the game. The long term effects may vary depending on different attributes, which I divided into two groups.

This is of course not an exhaustive list.

### Providing learning tools

- Did the game generalize enough, so that the player feels like the more they learn the better they will be in the game? as opposed to being predictable enough so that the user can learn exactly what they need and only that.
- Did the user learn how to learn independently or did they rely on specific instructions in the game?

### providing learning motivation

- Why did the user not want to learn in the first place? If it's because of a sense of incapability, games are great. If it's lack of interest, the long term effect could be negligible.
- Did what the player learn in the game turn out useful for the player in real life? Did the player see it as a positive outcome of learning, or as an outcome of the game?
- Did a motivation swap occur? sometimes the user may be one that learns for fun, and after playing the game they will only learn for points etc.

Since the concepts 'game' and 'learn' are so wide and subjective, I'm doubtful you can get a clear cut answer on this question.

Comment: Are these just your thoughts, or are they based on scientific evidence?

Comment: @Christiaan My point was that you can't generalize to the long-term effects of games, as there are too many variables in what the game is and what kind of learning you're talking about. These are some of the points that I think need addressing for the question to even be answerable